# SVN ci failes: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 255)

Tags: svn

I'm trying to commit dirrectory and svn fails with message:

```
D:\path\file.ext
Commit failed (details follow):
Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 255) with output:
Got 1 errors: 
* Block Merge Conflicts addon failed: Some parts of your commit look 
suspiciously like merge
conflict markers.  Please double-check your diff and try
committing again. To really commit, have your admin disable
the 'block merge conflicts' pre-commit hook.
(ref svn07:4hSwdSwjOkKgIp3G)
(ref svn07:Up2uVRcH74KRkoHB)
```

Any ideas what it can be and how to fix it?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-commit hooks are custom scripts installed by the server admin to prevent commits that break whatever rules/standards they have in place. Your commit looks like it's being blocked because you're trying to commit a file that matches some sort of pattern that the hook is blocking.

There's no single answer to this question, since a default subversion server *has no* pre-commit hooks. You need to talk to the server admin about this.

Comment: >There's no single answer to this question> I'm affraid you're right

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be saying that you have conflict markers still in your code.  That means lines of ">>>>", "<<<<" and "====".  This is probably because you had a conflict and simply marked it as resolved without actually resolving it.